# How to open a specific JPEG image inside a popup control?

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I'm working with WPF and C# to create a puzzle application.

I am trying to open a photo in a popup by selecting a JPEG image via the OpenFileDialog class.

The problem that I'm facing currently is nothing shows up in the popup (no selected image) and I don't know if I should actually be having an  tag in the XAML file because I don't know what the exact source for that would be (as the source would change depending on which image is opened).

Here is my code from the .cs file :

```
private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PatternWindow.IsOpen = true;

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialong1 = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialong1.Filter = "Image files (.jpg)|*.jpg";
        openFileDialong1.Title = "Open an Image File";
        openFileDialong1.ShowDialog();
        string fileName = openFileDialong1.FileName;
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Here is my code from the XAML file to show UI code:

```
             <StackPanel>
                <Popup Name="PatternWindow" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ButtonCanvas}" Placement="Relative" HorizontalOffset="280" VerticalOffset="50" IsOpen="False" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5"  Background="White">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="16">Chosen Pattern Window</TextBlock>
                            <Image Name="patternImage" Source= Width="200" Height="200"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why dont you show your ui code? you are not assigning the "image" to an image control

Comment: why dont you just fix the folder of images and pick the one up according to your cinditons here may be using LINQ.

Comment: I just edited my post to add in the UI code as well. I don't have a source for the <image> tag as I'm unsure how to add it yet keep it open to be anything the user chooses. @N.J

Comment: I have fixed a specific folder to hold all the images the user may be interested in, but they select a particular image through the openfiledialog. I don't understand how I could use LINQ as you suggest it.  @DeshDeepSingh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For UI, you don't need to write the Source in Image tag:

```
<Image Name="patternImage" Width="200" Height="200"/>
```

while for the code, you need to create BitmapImage from the selected file:

```
    private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PatternWindow.IsOpen = true;

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialong1 = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialong1.Filter = "Image files (.jpg)|*.jpg";
        openFileDialong1.Title = "Open an Image File";
        openFileDialong1.ShowDialog();
        string fileName = openFileDialong1.FileName;
        try
        {
            //here you create a bitmap image from filename
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(fileName);
            bi.EndInit();
            patternImage.Source = bi;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //throw exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you so much! I had tried creating a bitmap image previously but I didn't know about the other properties (cacheoption, createoptions, urisource) you have applied to the bitmap image. I shall read about them on the MSDN website now.

Comment: Unless you *really* need the `OnLoad` and `IgnoreImageCache` flags, you could just write `patternImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName));`

Comment: IgnoreImageCache: loads images without using an existing image cache. This option should only be selected when images in a cache need to be refreshed. -> I think it should be use in this case because the image could be changed several times based on user selection.

Answer (score -1):

The wpf image control will work given a path, have you tried...

patternImage.Source = new BitmapSource(new Uri(file name));

... In your event handler?

Edited based on feedback

Comment: Yes, I had tried that but it gave an error saying 'Cannot convert type string to System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. 
currarpickt's answer works

Comment: @naaz I have added an edit that should work if you're still looking for options.